# Independence of two coin tosses

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

Two fair coins are tossed (independently of each other). Let A be the event that both coins show head, and B be the event that both coins show tail.

Are A and B independent?

I'm a little confused about this. Am I correct in saying they are independent and mutually exclusive? Since if A happens, the probability of B happening if they were tossed again is unchanged?

Comment: **Hint** Does $\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)$ ?

Comment: $P(A \cap B) = 0$ because it is impossible for both events to occur simultaneously, so they must not be independent? $P(A) = 0.25$ & $P(B) = 0.25$ so $P(A \cap B) \neq P(A) \cdot P(B)$ ?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: yes that work (and as you said, since if $A$ occurs, then $B$ doesn't occurs, and thus, $B$ has a dependance on $A$, because if you know $A$, you know $B$ as well). Therefore, they can't be independent :-)

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you so much! :D